# UISplitViewController Master Content Width

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, mvvmcross, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a `UISplitViewController` in my application (MvvmCross / Xamarin iOS) and for some reason I cannot get the content to respect the dimensions of the available view areas.

In the situation shown in the screenshot the master view is hosting a `UIViewController` with a `TableView` inside.  All the layouts are done with constraints and work fine on their own when running in an iPhone emulator.

As soon as I switching to running on an iPad some custom code I have in my presenter shows this same view in the master panel of a `UISplitViewController` but in this situation the constraints seem to be ignored and I end up with a view that looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the right hand side of the table cell is now way off the viewable area of the master panel of the `UISplitViewController`.

Both the `UITableView` and the `UITableCell` both use `View.Frame` as their initial size (I've tried `View.Bounds` as well).

How can I get the cells and / or table to respect the bounds of the `UISplitViewController` available space?

Comment: Can you provide some information of which constraints you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Cheesebarons question I found my solution (cause).

I have a set of methods in a helper class that I use to generate my "default" UIViews.

One of these methods creates my default UITableView:

```
public static UITableView CreateDefaultTableView(CGRect rect, UITableViewStyle style)
{
    var tv = new UITableView(rect, style)
    {
        AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight,
        SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine,
        SeparatorColor = IosConstants.DefaultTableSeparatorColor,
        BackgroundColor = IosConstants.DefaultViewBackgroundColor
    };

    return tv;
}
```

Changing:

```
AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight,
```

To:

```
AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All,
```

Schoolboy error!